# Create new input for local storage

Tags: local-storage

Incrementing and storing the scores on local storage are working fine. Score gets incremented depending if game is won or lost. When I refresh the page (scores go to 0) and start playing again, it starts updating the same local storage from the beginning.

Is it possible to leave the last local storage as it is and set/start with the new one when page is refreshed?

js

```
function gameWon() {
    if (animalStatus === answer) {
        let oldScore = parseInt(document.getElementById("win").innerText);
        document.getElementById("win").innerText = ++oldScore;
        document.getElementById("key-container").innerHTML = `Well done! That was correct!<br> <button id="play-again" 
        onclick="playAgain()">Play again!</button>`;
        localStorage.setItem("wins", document.getElementById("win").innerText);
    }
};

function gameLost() {
    if (wrongGuess === 6) {
        let oldScore = parseInt(document.getElementById("loss").innerText);
        document.getElementById("loss").innerText = ++oldScore;
        document.getElementById("key-container").innerHTML = `Unfortunately you ran out of possible guesses.<br>
        Correct answer was: ${answer}!<br><button id="play-again" onclick="playAgain()">Play again!</button>`;
        localStorage.setItem("losses", document.getElementById("loss").innerText);
    }
};
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what is the intention. The point of local storage is to persist even if the page is reloaded. If you don't want this behavior, you don't need to use the local storage at all, normal variables will do just fine. If you want to persist the score for the next time the page is opened, make sure to read the old value from the local storage after the page is loaded to initialize the state with the correct value.

Comment: Hi Chris! Thank you for the answer.  My question is: is it possible to start saving new set of scores each time page is refreshed?

Comment: Out of curiosity: if you want to start a new set of scores each time the page is refreshed, then why bother storing it in the local storage at all? If you just declare a normal top-level variable in your code and keep using that, it won't persist through a reload. It's that very persistency limitation of variables that the local storage is meant to overcome. It feels like you've chosen to use a sharpie instead of the default pencil, and now ask how to make it erasable.

Comment: Hi Chris. Thank you for your question. I am only learning javascript, so am a newbie. On my course, my mentor asked me to store the scores in local storage. In my mind this was what I was supposed to do. Create new set of scores each time page reloads aka someone else plays it. Maybe you are right and I should ask my mentor to clarify.

Comment: Yes, that sounds like a good idea. Maybe it was your mentor's intention to let you implement a score that persists when the page is reloaded. This way, if the website was hosted on a server, each visitor's browser[-profile] tracks its own stat records, so I can track mine, you can track yours, etc. That's what local storage is quite often used for.

Comment: That was my thought as well. I asked my mentor about how should I have it. Waiting for the reply. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I’m understanding the question correctly, you can initialize a key to be used for local storage on page load. Ie maybe the current time stamp in ms.

```
const storageKey = +new Date();
```

Then later to access localStorage, you can do

```
localStorage.setItem(storageKey, JSON.stringify({ 
  wins: document.getElementById("win").innerText,
  losses: document.getElementById("loss").innerText  
}));
```

So to be able to have new localStorage values per refresh  session like this, you’d need to structure your data so that the access key is whatever storage key you’d want to use E.g. time in ms, and the value should now be an object containing wins and losses

Alternatively you can keep the wins and losses as separate keys if you prefix those with your storage key

E.g.

```
localStorage.setItem(
  storageKey + “_wins”, 
  document.getElementById("win").innerText
);

localStorage.setItem(
  storageKey + “_losses”, 
  document.getElementById("loss").innerText
);
```

The idea is that every time the page loads, the time in ms will be different. So next time the page is reloaded, you’ll get a new storage key and be able to access/ update fresh wins and losses in localStorage.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. I just need to convert the date into something readable like hours, minutes and seconds.